# Had to wipe the boot partition because of Windows. It was also the partition that my Linux installation was using. Cant boot anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, grub-efi

I have 2 SSDs:
One of the SSDs has the windows installation with other windows partitions one of which is the boot partition. this boot partition is what grub and windows both were using.
The other ssd had 3 partitions - Linux Swap, the Linux root and my home folder.
Notice there is no boot partition on this SSD.

I had to format the boot partition on the first SSD because windows was giving me the
error: file

```
'/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found
```

so I tried several methods and the one that worked required formatting the partition.
After that of course grub was gone.I tried booting and it didn't so I made a live installation disk and ran boot-repair which said it fixed the problem but it didn't and now upon booting I reach the screen that says:

"GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal bash-like line editing....or file combinations

grub>"

I can still boot to Windows by selecting the entry that says "Windows Boot Manager (my first SSD's serial number)" in the boot menu

To reach this grub command line thing, I have to select the boot entry that says

"Neon 5.20.4 (my first SSD's serial number)"

Comment: sadly it doesn't. i dont think i need to repair grub or anything.

Comment: I like to have an ESP - efi system partition on every drive, but Ubuntu and many then based on Ubuntu only uses the ESP on first drive. Your error was probably from Windows fast start up being on which sets hibernation flag, so grub2 could not find the boot file. You may have to reinstall grub using live installer or Boot-Repair from live installer if you want gui help. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair